# how to solve the examples that are in the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task: "
Write a program that solves a math example from a file and also writes the result back to the file.

Example:
String in file

```
34 + 22 - 11 * 10
```

After running your program

```
34 + 22 - 11 * 10 = -54
```

That is, the answer was written to the file after the calculation!

and I don't understand a little how this can be done, maybe there is a library, I tried it through readlines and eval, nothing worked

Comment: You have provided no evidence that you have tried anything.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. The first and easiest of them all is to use python 'eval' function. However, this may pose security risks and it may support operators which you don't want and you cannot customize the syntax. Or you can write your very own math interpreter, although it is not as easy and I would recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88lmIMHhYNs&list=PLZQftyCk7_Sdu5BFaXB_jLeJ9C78si5_3 as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is exactly how you thought

```
f = open("text.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines() 
for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip(), "=",eval(line))
f.close()
```

where the `rstrip` function was used only for formatting nicely the output

Comment: thank you so much, but im sorry for my so stupid question but,how can i saave the output in the file?

Comment: Use file write function https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/writing-to-file-in-python/